# How to re-direct user by setting the retURL from a visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I have a scenario, where users clicks a button from Opty which invokes a flow by passing the Opty ID as a variable. Now I am creating other child object in the flow and have to redirect user to that record and not Opportunity. Any help on design steps will be of great help.

Comment: This will be coming in a future release (I think Spring 16) - but as of now, Mohith's documentation on setting it through apex and VF is the only way you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

- You can pass variables from your flow to apex class and then from
  apex to your Visualforce
- You can configure finishlocation to redirect .

To get you started here is documentation link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_setting_values.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm

Comment: I am aware of the above design technique already, but the reason for posting is to see if I am missing anything where I can do a little JavaScipt hack on the button. Any thoughts on that ?